# Why is the maximum error large when the loss is small in elliptic partial differential equation approximation using neural networks in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to approximate the solution of elliptic partial differential equation using Neural networks. Here's the code:

```
#PDE
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class Net(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')
        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, x, y):
        inputs = tf.concat([x, y], axis=1)
        x = self.hidden1(inputs)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x

def f(x, y):
    return tf.exp(-x) * (x - 2 + y**3 + 6 * y)

def trial_func(x, y, net):
    A = (1 - x) * y**3 + x * (1 + y**3) * np.exp(-1) + (1 - y) * x * (tf.exp(-x) - np.exp(-1))     + y * [(1 + x) * tf.exp(-x) -(1 - x - 2 * x * np.exp(-1))]
    u = A + x * (1 - x) * y * (1 - y) * net(x, y)
    return u

def loss_func(d2udx2, d2udy2, x, y, net):
    u = trial_func(x, y, net)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(d2udx2 + d2udy2 - f(x, y)))

def exact_solution(x, y):
    return tf.exp(-x)*(x+y**3)

x_train = np.linspace(0, 1, 100, dtype=np.float32)
y_train = np.linspace(0, 1, 100, dtype=np.float32)
x_train, y_train = np.meshgrid(x_train, y_train)

x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train, dtype=tf.float32)


u_train = tf.zeros_like(x_train)

model = Net()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

@tf.function
def compute_gradients(x, y, u):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch([x, y])
        u_pred = trial_func(x, y, model)
        d2udx2_pred = tape.gradient(tape.gradient(u_pred, x), x)
        d2udy2_pred = tape.gradient(tape.gradient(u_pred, y), y)
        loss = loss_func(d2udx2_pred, d2udy2_pred, x, y, model)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss, gradients

for epoch in range(1000):
    loss, gradients = compute_gradients(x_train, y_train, u_train)
    
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {loss.numpy()}")

# Reshape the input data for plotting
x_test = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y_test = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x_test, y_test = np.meshgrid(x_test, y_test)
x_test = tf.constant(x_test, dtype=tf.float32)
y_test = tf.constant(y_test, dtype=tf.float32)

# Evaluate the predicted values
u_pred = trial_func(x_test, y_test, model)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Reshape the predicted values
u_pred = np.reshape(u_pred.numpy(), x_test.shape)

# Plotting the actual and predicted graph
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Actual function values
ax.plot_surface(x_test, y_test, exact_solution(x_test, y_test), cmap='viridis', alpha=0.5, label='Actual')

# Predicted function values
ax.plot_surface(x_test, y_test, u_pred, cmap='plasma', alpha=0.8, label='Predicted')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('u')
ax.set_title('Actual vs. Predicted Solution')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Compute the error
error = np.abs(exact_solution(x_test, y_test) - u_pred)

# Maximum error
max_error = np.max(error)

# Plotting the error graph
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Error values
ax.plot_surface(x_test, y_test, error, cmap='Reds', alpha=0.8, label='Error')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Error')
ax.set_title('Error')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

print(f"Maximum error: {max_error}")
```

This code results in loss of 10<sup>-4</sup> which is pretty decent. But while calculating maximum error it results in 1.47 which is large. This imply that approximation is not good. My question: why is maximum error large when the loss is small? Also how can I reduce the maximum error so that approximation becomes good. Just want to inform that I've tried changes in hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Your loss function is specified in a way that it returns small losses for what you consider large deviations; thereby, your model will barely improve on its errors. For this reason, you can see a bad model performance even though your loss function tells you that everything's going great.

**Recommendation:** Revise loss function

**Approach:**

- I modified your code to retrieve the individual losses per observations, as well as the predictions during the training
- I computed the individual errors and randomly chose a observation where the error is "large", where I set "large" to an individual error larger than `>0.1`
- For each epoch, I randomly chose an observation with a large error and printed it's `x value`, `y value`, `prediction for u`, `expected u`, `absolute error` and `individual loss`. Below are some examples; note how small individual loss is compared to absolute loss

First Example:

```
Epoch: 200, Loss: 0.0005683581111952662
Random observation where error is large
x_train: 0.6767676472663879
y_train: 0.8888888955116272
u_exact: 0.7009372115135193
u_pred: 1.5870349407196045
abs_error: 0.8860977292060852
individual_loss: 0.0003568194806575775
```

Second Example:

```
Epoch: 700, Loss: 9.580078040016815e-05
Random observation where error is large
x_train: 0.6565656661987305
y_train: 1.0
u_exact: 0.8591437339782715
u_pred: 1.8252918720245361
abs_error: 0.9661481380462646
individual_loss: 0.00018366181757301092
```

Third Example:

```
Epoch: 800, Loss: 0.00021436536917462945
Random observation where error is large
x_train: 0.1818181872367859
y_train: 0.8585858345031738
u_exact: 0.6792932152748108
u_pred: 0.9082082509994507
abs_error: 0.2289150357246399
individual_loss: 5.41552908543963e-05
```

Code I used:

```
#PDE
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class Net(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')
        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, x, y):
        inputs = tf.concat([x, y], axis=1)
        x = self.hidden1(inputs)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x

def f(x, y):
    return tf.exp(-x) * (x - 2 + y**3 + 6 * y)

def trial_func(x, y, net):
    A = (1 - x) * y**3 + x * (1 + y**3) * np.exp(-1) + (1 - y) * x * (tf.exp(-x) - np.exp(-1))     + y * [(1 + x) * tf.exp(-x) -(1 - x - 2 * x * np.exp(-1))]
    u = A + x * (1 - x) * y * (1 - y) * net(x, y)
    return u

def loss_func(d2udx2, d2udy2, x, y, net):
    """Change: Return both aggregated loss and individual losses"""
    u = trial_func(x, y, net)
    loss_per_observation = tf.square(d2udx2 + d2udy2 - f(x, y))
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss_per_observation), loss_per_observation

def exact_solution(x, y):
    return tf.exp(-x)*(x+y**3)

x_train = np.linspace(0, 1, 100, dtype=np.float32)
y_train = np.linspace(0, 1, 100, dtype=np.float32)
x_train, y_train = np.meshgrid(x_train, y_train)

x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train, dtype=tf.float32)


u_train = tf.zeros_like(x_train)

model = Net()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

@tf.function
def compute_gradients(x, y, u):
    """Change: Make function return `loss_per_observation` and `u_pred`"""
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch([x, y])
        u_pred = trial_func(x, y, model)
        d2udx2_pred = tape.gradient(tape.gradient(u_pred, x), x)
        d2udy2_pred = tape.gradient(tape.gradient(u_pred, y), y)
        loss, loss_per_observation = loss_func(d2udx2_pred, d2udy2_pred, x, y, model)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss, gradients, loss_per_observation, u_pred

for epoch in range(1000):
    loss, gradients, loss_per_observation, u_pred = compute_gradients(x_train, y_train, u_train)
    
    
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {loss.numpy()}")

        # Change: calculate expected outcome and error
        u_exact = exact_solution(x_train, y_train)
        error = np.abs(u_exact - u_pred)

        # Get observations where error is large, randomly choose one observation
        dim1, dim2, dim3 = np.where(error > 0.1)

        from random import choice
        random_index_dim2 = choice(dim2)
        random_index_dim3 = choice(dim3)

        # Get all key values for given observation
        print("Random observation where error is large")
        print(f"x_train: {x_train.numpy()[random_index_dim2][random_index_dim3]}")
        print(f"y_train: {y_train.numpy()[random_index_dim2][random_index_dim3]}")
        print(f"u_exact: {u_exact.numpy()[random_index_dim2][random_index_dim3]}")
        print(f"u_pred: {u_pred.numpy()[0][random_index_dim2][random_index_dim3]}")
        print(f"abs_error: {error[0][random_index_dim2][random_index_dim3]}")
        print(f"individual_loss: {loss_per_observation.numpy()[random_index_dim2][random_index_dim3]}")
```

Comment: Definitely loss function plays a major role in approximation. Here, basically PDE is defined as partial_d2u/partial_dx2 + partial_d2u/partial_dy2 = f(x,y). So our target is to make partial_d2u/partial_dx2 + partial_d2u/partial_dy2 - f(x,y) converge to 0 which is why loss function is defined in this way. Is there any way I can improve on max error?

Comment: One question - what's the purpose of `exact_solution()`, `f()`, and `trial_func()`?

Comment: `exact_solution()` is just for comparison purpose. To see how predicted solution is different from exact solution of [PDE](https://shorturl.at/hyCU2). `f(x,y)` is the function defined in PDE. `trial_func()` is intentionally defined in a specific way so that it satisfies boundary conditions. For more info please have a look at page 3, eq. `(21)`, `(22)` & `(23)` of this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=712178&tag=1).